# Can a derived class define a member with the same name as a member from its base class? How to differentiate their usage?

Tags: c++, class, radix

In C++ you can put a member in a base class and a member with the same name in the inherited class.

How can I access a specific one in the inherited class?

Comment: The question you should be asking is why do you have classes in the same inheritance hierarchy that have duplicately named members that are distinct?  See Effective C++ Item 33.

Comment: If your question is how to access the derived method from a base reference or pointer, add a comment. As it is written the question can be interpreted in two ways (and all answers deal with just one of them)

Comment: @TheJuice, I am not sure if this isn't a bad practice, but I've seen this in the code which uses the `PIMPL` idiom: base class has its own `m_pImpl` different from the child's one.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In that case you should fully qualify a member name.

```
class A
{
public:
  int x;
};


class B : public A
{
public:
  int x;
  B() 
  { 
    x = 0;
    A::x = 1;
  }
};
```

Comment: I thought it always worked like this. But with GCC 13, the compiler generates an error for this: `invalid use of non-static data member`.

Answer (score 10):

If you specify the name you'll access the one in the inherited class automatically. If you mean how do you access the one in the base class, use Base::member

Answer (score 9):

One approach (already mentioned in all other answers) is to use the qualified member name, like `Base::member`. It can be used in conjunction with explicit access through `this` pointer, if that's your style: `this->Base::member`.

Another approach is to perform access through `this` pointer explicitly converted to the base class type: `((Base *) this)->member`.

Of course, the above  references to `this` pointer are made under assumption that you are trying to access the member from within some non-static member function of the class. To access if from "outside", the same tricks can be applied to any other pointer (or reference): `some_pointer->Base::member` or `((Base *) some_pointer)->member`.

For data members these two approaches are equivalent. For member functions they can lead to different results with virtual functions. For this reason, in general, the first approach should be preferred.

Answer (score 8):

To access the hidden member in the base class you have to prefix the member name with the base class name.  See below:

```
class A
{
protected:
   int i;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
   void foo( void )
   {
      int a_i = A::i;
      int b_i = i;
      int b_i_as_well = B::i;
   }
private:
   int i;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

Qualify your call, `f()`, with a class name: `SpecificClass::f()`.

Answer (score 4):

By prefixing it with `classname::`.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Base {
    int memfcn();
};

struct Derived : Base {
    int memfcn(int);
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    Base b;
    d.Base::memfcn();  //you can even use :: in conjunction with dot(.). This is new to me.
}
```