# double colon for instance variables in c++

Tags: c++

I have always been under the impression that `<class>::<variable>` is for accessing static members. However, I am surprised to find out that the following compiles just fine. (I would have used `this->` as shown in the inline comment.)

Further investigation on Google/StackOverflow doesn't show anything pertinent to this behavior, I wonder if anyone could shed some light on this.

```
class Test {
    private:
        int x;
    public:
    void set_x(int x) {
        // this->x = x;
        Test::x = x;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

ENV: clang version 7.0.0- (trunk)

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name

Comment: It should be here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/qualified_lookup

Comment: This is qualifying the variable name and can be useful if a base class and inherited class have colliding names - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631128/c-inherited-class-has-member-of-same-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631128/c-inherited-class-has-member-of-same-name).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `::` is the scope-resolution operator and can be used to specify which of a number of symbols of the same name but different but visible scope the reference refers to.

Either scope-resolution or `this->` may be used in this example, but scope-resolution itself has more general applicability within the language.

Answer (score 0):

http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.qual#class.qual

> If the nested-name-specifier of a qualified-id nominates a class, the name
>   specified after the nested-name-specifier is looked up in the scope of the
>   class ([class.member.lookup]), except for the cases listed below.  The name
>   shall represent one or more members of that class or of one of its base
>   classes ([class.derived]).  [ Note: A class member can be referred to using a
>   qualified-id at any point in its potential scope ([basic.scope.class]).  — end
>   note  ]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it merely specifies the class name/namespace the object was declared in. There can be more contrived cases, like this one:

```
struct Base {
    virtual int answer() const { return 42; }
};

struct Left: public virtual Base {
    virtual int answer() const { return 314; } // raise the heat
};

struct Right: public virtual Base {
    virtual int answer() const { return -42; } // to the other side
};

struct Bottom: Left, Right {
    virtual int answer() const { return Base::answer(); } // back to basics
};

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    Bottom b;
    std::cout << b.answer() << std::endl;           // 42
    std::cout << b.Right::answer() << std::endl;    // -42
    std::cout << b.Left::answer() << std::endl;     // 314
    std::cout << b.Base::answer() << std::endl;     // again, 42
}
```

The thing with static members, you cannot access them other way (and they cannot be virtual, btw.) (Still, if class `Child` derives `Base` and both define a static member `staticMember`, you should use qualified forms — either `Base::staticMember` or `Child::staticMember` — to disambiguate between the two; unqualified version refers to `Child`'s one in this case.)

But non-static methods have an object context inside them, so members *can* be used unqualified — still they *can* be used other way, too.

P.S. Where did that `this->` originate from? I sometimes see it every here and there, still nobody has been able to explain why.

Comment: You can totally use static members unqualified if you're inside the class scope.

Comment: You can use member access operators on an object for static members too

Comment: `this->` is useful for accessing members of dependent bases. It is also somewhat idiomatic in Java to have parameters of constructors with the same name as members, and write `this->a = a`

Comment: Yes, definitely.

Comment: @PasserBy but there are other ways, eh?

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons to qualify with class name an instance variable (or member function).  This list is not exhaustive, and only mentions cases where we would use it on object instances, not types:

- Inside a member function, if derived and parent have the same member name, the derived name hides the base.  Qualification can allow access to the base.  This applies to both variables and member functions.
- If inside a member function in hierarchy with multiple inheritance, it can select between which parent you want to use.
- It can be used to bypass the virtual function dispatch mechanism by calling the function implementation in the type specified, rather than in the most overriding type.  Example: `d.Base::foo();`
- It can be used to specify a member that was hidden by a local variable, similar to qualifying a member with this->  (Though I've never seen this done, and prefer this-> instead.)
- It is frequently used in conjunction with a "using" declaration, to bring base class function names into the overload set of the derived class that adds some of its own with the same name.  Without this, the base names would be hidden.