# Accessing Member Variables of Derived Structs Without Casting

Tags: c++

I have a bunch of derived structs. Is there any way for me to access the derived `width` without casting?

If I do this, I get `1`s and not `42` and `13`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
using namespace std;

struct BaseParams {
    virtual ~BaseParams() {}
    int width = 1;
};

struct VectorParams : BaseParams {
    int width = 42;
};

struct MatrixParams : BaseParams {
    int width = 13;
};

int main()
{

    std::deque<BaseParams *> params;
    VectorParams *vectorParams = new VectorParams;
    MatrixParams *matrixParams = new MatrixParams;
    
    params.push_back(vectorParams);
    params.push_back(matrixParams);
    
    for (auto &param : params) {
        std::cout << param->width << std::endl;
    }
    
    // Don't want to do this
    // for (auto &param : params) {
    //     MatrixParams *matrixParams = dynamic_cast<MatrixParams *>(param);
    //     if (matrixParams)
    //         std::cout << matrixParams->width << std::endl; 
    //     VectorParams *vectorParams = dynamic_cast<VectorParams *>(param);
    //     if (vectorParams)
    //         std::cout << vectorParams->width << std::endl;
    // }
    
    return 0;
}
```

If possible, I want to avoid casting because I have so many derived structs.

Comment: have you tried to make them public? as in `struct MatrixParams : public BaseParams`

Comment: Why do you use the same name for two different variables? `width` in `VectorParams` is a completely different variable from `width` in `BaseParams` so `VectorParams` has two variables both called `width`. Is this the intention? Or do you want one variable, which is set to 42 when making a VectorParams?

Comment: @Nole Ksum Yes, does not help

Comment: @user253751 My intention was to overwrite the `width` from `BaseParams`. But that's maybe not what I am actually doing.

Comment: @Fabian *"My intention was to overwrite the `width` from `BaseParams`."* -- It might be worth adding this to your question. Is this knowledge imported from a different language? It's not the C++ way of doing things.

Comment: Yeah, I modified some other code that already had a struct inheritance architecture like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To overwrite the width in BaseParams, instead of making a new variable, you can give VectorParams a constructor like this:

```
struct VectorParams : BaseParams {
    VectorParams() {
        width = 42;
    }
};
```

In fact constructors are always how variables are set in new objects. When you write

```
struct BaseParams {
    virtual ~BaseParams() {}
    int width = 1;
};
```

the compiler actually turns it into a constructor, similar to

```
struct BaseParams {
    virtual ~BaseParams() {}
    int width;
    BaseParams() {
        width = 1;
    }
};
```

Comment: Okay, I see. This worked. Thanks! However, I don't fully understand how the derived class can have two member variables with the same name and type? Why does my code result in `VectorParams` having two `width`s?

Comment: @Fabian *"I don't fully understand how the derived class can have two member variables with the same name and type?"* -- Technically, the members have different names. See [Can a derived class define a member with the same name as a member from its base class? How to differentiate their usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631128/) Briefly, using your code, there is `vectorParams->VectorParams::width` and `vectorParams->BaseParams::width`. The former (from the most derived class) can be shortened to `vectorParams->width`.

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot of sense. Thx!